# Podman Desktop integration with WSL

Tags: podman

I have installed Podman in Ubuntu 22.04 is it possible that I install Podman Desktop on my Windows host and connect it somehow to Podman installation inside WSL.

Same arrangement I had with Docker and Docker Desktop.